# echo $? returns jibberish when the return value of a cpp main func returns high numbers

Tags: c++, linux, echo, return-value

I wrote the most basic main func:

```
int main()
{
 cout << "just to see it works";
 return 1234; 
}
```

afterwords I built the file and runned the file:

```
gcc <cpp fileName>.cc -lstdc++ -o main
./main
```

afterwords I ran:

```
echo $?
```

and my return value was **210** when I returned 999 instead of 1234 I got around 231 and when I returned numbers from around 0 to 250 I received the same number as aspected.

Why when returning high numbers I receive numbers around 210?

P.S.
I was unable to find questions close enough to this one. Also, I didn't find in the manual of echo a good explanation of echo $? or a manual for echo $?

Comment: Looks like you get numbers modulo 256.

Comment: Convert the number to hexadecimal and take only the last 2 digits (aka mod 256). `1234 = 0x4d2`, `0xd2 = 210` . That seems to be what you are seeing

Comment: echo doesn't know about $?.  That's done by the shell.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right that it is module 256. I wonder why it is like this but that already less relevant.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate, I think it is not exactly a duplicate since the other question knows that echo $? gives modulo 256 and this question is for people who did notice this.

Comment: Related: http://blogs.perl.org/users/mauke/2011/09/exit-statuses-and-how-works.html

Comment: @melpomene perfect this really helps :-)